# Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi failing to GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>()

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm following the azure-devops-dotnet-samples CreateBugUsingClientLib() sample pretty closely, but

```
GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>()
```

is throwing:

InnerException:  {"Could not cast or convert from System.String to Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor."}   System.Exception {System.ArgumentException}

Message:  "Error converting value \"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;stuff\me@contoso.com\" to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.IdentityDescriptor'. Path 'authenticatedUser.descriptor'

The full sample is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Quickstarts/dotnet/WitQuickStarts/Samples/CreateBug.cs

All my NuGets are up to date.

```
// string uri = "https://teams.visualstudio.com/defaultCollection/"
// string pat = "personal access token";
// string project = "Ateam";
// string path = "autobug";
// string title = "you broke it";
// string steps = "you touched it";

var patchDoc = new JsonPatchDocument
{
    new JsonPatchOperation() { Operation = Operation.Add, Path = "/fields/System.Title", Value = title },
    new JsonPatchOperation() { Operation = Operation.Add, Path = "/fields/System.AreaPath", Value = path },
    new JsonPatchOperation() { Operation = Operation.Add, Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.ReproSteps", Value = steps },
    new JsonPatchOperation() { Operation = Operation.Add, Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority", Value = "2" },
    new JsonPatchOperation() { Operation = Operation.Add, Path = "/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Severity", Value = "2" }
};

var cred = new VssBasicCredential("", pat);
var conn = new VssConnection(new Uri(uri), cred);
var client = conn.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

Comment: How did you define "stuff\me@contoso.com" in your code?

Comment: That was content from the personal access token.

Answer (score 2):

We got this working with:

```
var client = new WorkItemTrackingHttpClient(new Uri(uri), cred);
```

instead of:

```
var conn = new VssConnection(new Uri(uri), cred);
var client = conn.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
```

Comment: This worked for me but I am trying to understand why does the explicit VssConnection object throw error. My theory is there's a peculiar discrepancy between TFS and VSS libraries.